# Access first list items in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

Is there any way to access the first element of the python series object that may contain a list in some entries

Example input

```
JUNE      0.1591
JULY      0.004
AUG       0.000
SEPT      NaN
OCT   [1.004, 0.000]
dtype: object
```

Desired output

```
JUNE      0.1591
JULY      0.004
AUG       0.000
SEPT      NaN
OCT   1.004
dtype: object
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context for this? Why is your data a mix of numbers and lists?

Comment: actual context is `[NaN, NaN]`, that was getting from a loop like ```testdata[month]=ttest_ind(x_sample[month], y_sample[month], equal_var=False)[0]```.

Comment: Difficult to know what’s going on based only on that. I was asking because I suspect there is a better way of solving this, or perhaps a way to avoid the issue entirely.

Comment: agree. I was working with https://github.com/thomasmaxwellnorman/Perturbseq_GI/blob/master/GI_activation_of_neighboring_genes.ipynb the `bootstrap_ratio` function breaks due to the list in the array produced by `bootstrap_t ` in my data. So was thinking to work around to take first element from array. Hope this clarify. Was avoiding this context to make it simple and could'nt think appropriate data structure being a python beginner

Comment: the exact error is ```ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Regarding that error, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10062954/11301900.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207145/discussion-between-shams-and-amc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using [`Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
s.mask(s.str.len().gt(1), s.str[0])

JUNE    0.1591
JULY     0.004
AUG          0
SEPT       NaN
OCT      1.004
```